# Related list is missing from page layout

Tags: page-layout, related-list

I've linked Cases with custom object using lookup relationship.
[image: Lookup relationship between custom object and Cases]

However the custom object page layout is missing the related list.
[image: Related lists on custom object]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named the Related List Label "Supplier Relations Escalation", so that is what it is called on the Page Layout. You can see it on the far right of your options.

Comment: what a catch ":)